# Has the release date of Shingeki no Kyojin's second season been announced?

Tags: attack-on-titan

I've been hearing/reading a lot of news about a second season of Shingeki no Kyojin since 2014. All the sites said that the release date would be in the end of 2015 or the first months of 2016.
We're in 2016 and there's still no season 2.

Is there any official source about a accurate release date? If so, what's the exact date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If so, what's the exact date?

The [second season](https://myanimelist.net/anime/25777/Shingeki_no_Kyojin_Season_2) of Attack on Titan was released as of April 1, 2017. It aired until June 17, 2017. It contained a total of 12 episodes.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately right now, **No there is not an official source with a release date for the second season** and as a result there is no exact date (as of yet).

A post on [Cross Map,](http://www.crossmap.com/news/attack-on-titan-season-2-spoilers-release-date-rumors-news-updates-24210)  ***an unofficial source***, (By Yumi Redfield On January 17, 2016) explains that:

> There have been rumors claiming that Attack on Titan season 2 will be released in February, but it is already mid-January, and still no confirmation for an Attack on Titan season 2 has been released by Tetsuro Araki, the Attack on Titan director.

A given (***unofficial***) explanation is:

> The major reason why Attack on Titan season 2 has taken years to release is because of the (very well thought of) agreement between Attack on Titan manga writer Hajime Isayama and the Attack on Titan anime director Tetsuro Araki that the manga should always be 4 arcs ahead of the anime adaptation. This agreement would ensure that the anime would not get ahead of the manga and end up deviating too much from the source material.

This answer is based on sources available on 19/01/2016 at 17:10pm BST.

[image]

Comment: The article is rather dubious, seeing that it has zero citation, and none of the anime sites report about the "explanation" for the delay. It seems like a speculation engineered to become news. I will leave my downvote here until you can cite a more reputable source.

Comment: I cited the only sources that I could find. I find your down vote harsh as I've only answered with what other sources have claimed. And it isn't my opinion so I have followed the rules of the site. My answer includes pretty much everything mentioned in the how to write a good answer help page

Comment: I downvote for the dubious source you cite, especially the part `reement between Attack on Titan manga writer Hajime Isayama and the Attack on Titan anime director Tetsuro Araki that the manga should always be 4 arcs ahead of the anime adaptation`, which doesn't appear in any reputable anime news site. The post has good presentation (as what the help page instructed), but the content still subjects to scrutiny.

Comment: Anime & manga stack exchange is meant to be fun with **friendly people** who can discuss and share their love for anime. Clearly you have forgotten this. All i've done is use the sources i could find to answer someone's question with the best possible answer i could give. If you have a problem with what the source says its not my fault, i didn't write it! Your criticism is not constructive as you cannot offer anything better

Comment: `If you have a problem with what the source says its not my fault, i didn't write it!` Even though you are not the one who write it, since you cite it, you should make sure that it's correct/credible. We are don't want our site to feed the rumor mill. Please don't take the downvote personally.

Answer (score 2):

The 2nd season of Attack on Titan is currently planned for Spring 2017 season !

Source: http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2016-07-03/attack-on-titan-anime-2nd-season-premieres-in-spring-2017/.103914

So, that means the 1st episode of season 2 should be released around the beginning of April 2017.